# Image collections are not recognized as the same size for processing

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have two merged collections of images (LANDSAT and LANDTREND).

```
  var collection = Collection.select(['NDVI_to_ajust'],['LANDSAT']).merge(
    imageCollection.select(["NDVI"], ["LTGEE"]))
```

I need to store as property NDVI values calculated by each image collection, separately in array form, in 50 different samples (which are as a FeatureCollection called "antropVegPrima"). I used "reduceRegions" to do this.

```
var triplets = collection.map(
    function(image) {
    return image.reduceRegions({
      collection: ignoradoSamples50, 
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(image.bandNames()), 
      scale: 30,
      tileScale: 4
    }).map(
      function(feature) {
      return feature.set({
        'imageID': image.id(),
        'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('Y-MM-dd')
      })
    });
  }).flatten();
```

However, I have a problem that the size of the LANDSAT (124 x124) images is not the same as the LANDTREND (123 X12) image collection.

I was able to run this script for a sample collection determination, available at this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a5a11822e71aeaf8461b1c258148220c)

However, for another collection of samples, the processing is not complete, as I demonstrated in this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0a6ee16cc8ba0661a675ebd0b27c05ea)